# php - how can I display sql sum result in echo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

what I will use to display the value of column?

```
 $a = get_by_sum($col,$id); 
 // $a will select from sql sum of visit where id is equal to sent id
```

if I print $a I will get the below output below:

```
Array 
    ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object 
        (
        [SUM(column)] => 180 
        ) 
     )
```

how to view the column in php page ?
what I mean, I want to put echo that shows the result 180 in my php page

Comment: Use an aliasing in your query for this like sum and then use `echo $a[0]->SUM`;

Comment: thank you, but it shows nothing on display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display '180' on your page, you can do this:

```
echo $a[0]->sum;
```

If you have several value, you will have to do a foreach() as follow,

```
foreach ($a as $value) {
    echo $value->sum;
}
```

But in your SQL Query, I would advice you to put an alias after your sum(**) to have a key which have a sense, something like,

```
SELECT SUM(xxx) as your_alias_name FROM ...
```

Comment: thank you, the problem was because I didn't put the alias after the SUM()

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone,

all answers was right but the problem was that I dont ha an alias after the sum()

I solve it this way,

I add alias
"SELECT SUM(**) as alias FROM"

the output changed to

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [alias] => 180 ) )
```

then I use the code

```
echo $a[0]->alias;
```

this allow me to get the 180 viewed in my page :)

Answer (score 0):

> I hope, you should use
>    echo  $a[0]->sum;